# Python Decryption cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken Exception

Tags: python-2.7

I am facing issues in decryption. I am passing the encrypted value, Facing issues with decryption. Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def decrypt_message(message):
    print('message recieved',message)
    key=Fernet.generate_key()
    print('key', key)
    f=Fernet(key)
    print(f)
    decrypted_message=f.decrypt(message)
    return decrypted_message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    decrypt_message("gAAAAABfXuoyHoPiHXpRmM6vVslU2B5u7lZ-Q1Q_zC0MbxbQomycVogHJdrkpej16uhX8KxDbvRe66n2Jew7GHS_YukIT0M9ew==")
```

Error:

```
root@5CG7242QFY:~# python decrypt.py
('message recieved', 'gAAAAABfXuoyHoPiHXpRmM6vVslU2B5u7lZ-Q1Q_zC0MbxbQomycVogHJdrkpej16uhX8KxDbvRe66n2Jew7GHS_YukIT0M9ew==')
('key', '4k8-dtzXqWSlA3wSfNoSa3UmNmXHBgu-bSbPO3uVfuI=')
<cryptography.fernet.Fernet object at 0x7fc8134b9d50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt.py", line 14, in <module>
    decrypt_message("gAAAAABfXuoyHoPiHXpRmM6vVslU2B5u7lZ-Q1Q_zC0MbxbQomycVogHJdrkpej16uhX8KxDbvRe66n2Jew7GHS_YukIT0M9ew==")
  File "decrypt.py", line 10, in decrypt_message
    decrypted_message=f.decrypt(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 103, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Answer (score 1):

Fernet tokens are symmetrically encrypted values. This means they can only be decrypted with the same key that was used to encrypt them. In your example you are generating a new key each time `decrypt_message()` is called and then trying to decrypt an existing token. If this worked it would be a catastrophic security problem.